# ev3dev python power script

Tags: python

ev3dev stretch version 14 April 2019 downloaded from here...

https://github.com/ev3dev/ev3dev-lang-python

Running this python script to see what is happening with power on my ev3dev. Works apart from the commented out code, which reports as unknown variables?

What should this read?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from ev3dev2.power import PowerSupply

power = PowerSupply()
print("amps",power.measured_amps)
print("volts",power.measured_volts)
print("type",power.type)
print("max_voltage",power.max_voltage)
print("min_voltage",power.min_voltage)
#print("measured voltage",measured_voltage)
#print("measured current",measured_current)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have `measured_voltage` and `measured_current` variables defined. Try this:

```
print("measured voltage",power.measured_voltage)
print("measured current",power.measured_current)
```